# Formik Validation on/off

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am new to React and your help would be much appreciated. I have the following form:

```js
 <Formik
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={ValidationSchema}
        enableReinitialize={true}>
        {({ values, handleSubmit,  isSubmitting, dirty }) => (
          <>
            <UnsavedFormPrompt when={dirty} formName="X form" />

            <Table.Row>
              <Table.Cell>
                <Field required name="X1" component={InputField}/>{' '}
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>
                <Field required name="X2" component={InputField} />{' '}
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>
                <Field required name="X3" component={SelectField} options={options}/>
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>
                <Field required name="X4" component={InputField} />{' '}
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>
                <Field required name="X5" component={DateField} />
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>
                <Field required name="X6" component={DateField} />
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>
                <Field required name="X7" component={InputField} />{' '}
              </Table.Cell>

              {foo && (
                <Table.Cell textAlign="center" className={styles.UpdateButtons}>
                  <Button
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                    type="submit"
                    color="blue"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}>
                    Update
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    onClick={this.removeX1}
                    basic
                    color="grey"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}>
                    Remove
                  </Button>
                </Table.Cell>
              )}

              {!foo && (
                <Table.Cell textAlign="center">
                  <Button
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                    type="submit"
                    color="blue"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}>
                    Add
                  </Button>
                </Table.Cell>
              )}
            </Table.Row>
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

With X1Schema validation:

```js
import * as yup from 'yup';

export const ValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  X1: yup.string().required('X1 is required.'),
  X2: yup.string().required('X2 is required'),
  X3: yup
  .string()
  .nullable()
  .required('X3 is required.'),
  X4: yup.number().required("X4 is required"),
  X5: yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
    .required('X5 is required.'),
  X6: yup
  .string()
  .nullable()
  .required('X6 is required.'),
  limit: yup.number().required("X7 is required"),
});
```

When pressing the `Remove` button the `ValidationSchema` is checking the fields and the FE cannot reach my BE endpoint because of the validation schema.

`RemoveX1` :

```js
RemoveX1 = async () => {
    const { foo , foo2, endpoint_that_needs_reaching } = this.props;

    const data = {
      foo: foo.pk
    }

    const { success, errors } = await deleteFoo(
      foo2.id,
      foo.id,
      prepareFormData(data)
    );

    if (success) {
      notifySuccess(`Foo ${foo.name} removed.`);
      fetchFoos();
    }

    if (!success) {
      notifyErrors(errors);
    }
  };
```

I need to disable the Formik validation somehow on `Remove` press.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the type of your Remove button? Does setting it to `type="button"` help avoid the submitting the form?

Comment: It is a react button, unfortunately setting `type="button"` does not fix the issue.

Comment: Could you move the button out of the form? It seems like it's submitting the form and triggering your validations, yet it doesn't seem to be using any information from the form.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with a 'react button'... what library is providing that component? Check the docs and see what props it accepts (it might ignore a `type` prop).